# Обрезается фон страницы относительно контента

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, background

Есть такой дизайн

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на правое и левое изображение
Вот тот же дизайн только для меньшего разрешения экрана

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите при уменьшении экрана фоновые картинки не смещаются относительно контента - они обрезаются по краям

Вот как сделать что бы они по краям не обрезались?

PS

```
background: url(/img/leftTopBack.png) no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Такой код не работает

Comment: Вообще ничего непонятно

Comment: background-position: center top; если верно поняла задачу.

Answer (score 3):

### Решение SVG

Легко решает проблемы с позиционированием и адаптивностью изображений при изменении размеров дисплея. Изображение не обрежется по краям, если вы его добавите внутрь svg файла.

```
<image xlink:href="leftTopBack.png" width="100%" height="100%"  />
```

При уменьшении, увеличении размеров экрана, контейнера, в который лучше обернуть, добавленный инлайн svg, изображение будет находиться в одной системе координат с SVG и меняться пропорционально.

```html
 <style>
    .container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:grey;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: 0% 100%;
    }

    </style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 272" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   
     <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDLMO.png" width="100%" height="100%"  />

     </svg>    
</div>
```

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Если ответ вам был полезен, не забудьте пожалуйста поставить плюс и чекбокс.